# Selecting a criteria inside another criteria using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to get the following SQL query using NHibernate's criteria API?

```
SELECT a.someColumn FROM aTable a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM bTable WHERE xyz = 'something') b on a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a SQL sub-select using NHibernate DetachedCriteria like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779517/13855). For the query you provided, why not just do:

```
SELECT a.someColumn FROM aTable a LEFT OUTER JOIN bTable b on a.Id = b.Id WHERE b.xyz = 'something'
```

Comment: I can't do this because I want to retrieve records from A that reference B whose xyz is not 'something'.